# how to ? automatic installation hdp with ambari for nightly build (CI)

Tags: hadoop, puppet, hortonworks-data-platform, puppetlabs-apache

I am searching for instruction how I can manage to install hortonworks (hdp) cluster, using ambari as a silent installation.

I saw in the manual of ambari-server that there are option to do it but it used the default values.

```
amabri-server setup -s
```

(Setup runs silently. Accepts all default prompt values.)

How I can do it? And how can I change the default values?

The reason I need it is for our nightly build.

Comment: i want to automate the wizard also is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't a very elegant solution but I used `expect` to automate the installation by spawning ambari-server setup and automatically putting in preconfigured values into the prompts.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of necro: you can use flags to kinda automate installation process. View a list of flags via

> ambari-server setup –help